# How to add a "myfields >= TRUNC(sysdate)" clause with ExpressionBuilder to a ReportQuery (Toplink)

Tags: java, toplink

I've this code

```
            Expression expRefr = new ExpressionBuilder();
            expRefr = expRefr.and(new ExpressionBuilder().get("refrCd").equal(referenza));
            expRefr = expRefr.and(new ExpressionBuilder().get("enteCd").equal(pEnteCd));
            expRefr = expRefr.and(new ExpressionBuilder().get("dpCdTipo").equal("V"));

            final ReportQuery refrQuery = 
                new ReportQuery(BoEnteRefrPrmz.class, expRefr);
```

i need to add a `dpDtFineVald>= TRUNC(sysdate)` clause to the WHERE condition, what should i do?
Something like

```
expRefr = 
   expRefr.and(new ExpressionBuilder().get("dpDtFineVald").greaterThanEqual(//What should i put here?);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea about toplink or Expression. I just tried this with what I got from Google. Please check.

```
String format = "MM/dd/yyyy";

expRefr = expRefr.and(new ExpressionBuilder().get("dpDtFineVald").truncateDate(format).greaterThanEqual(new ExpressionBuilder().currentDate().truncateDate(format));
```

Comment: What worked was `expRefr = expRefr.and(new ExpressionBuilder().get("dpDtFineVald").greaterThanEqual(new ExpressionBuilder().literal("SYSDATE").getFunction("TRUNC")));` But you helped me going in the right direction!